# How to change the string format of a datagrid column in WPF with vb.net programmatically?

Tags: wpf, vb.net, datagrid

Basically, what I want to do is the WinForm Datagridview equivalent of `dgvPreview.Columns(4).DefaultCellStyle.Format = "#,##0.00"`
But instead of Datagridview, it's with Datagrid in WPF. Best I can do is assign a datatable to a Datagrid and change its alignment property.

```
DataGridPreview.ItemsSource = dtPreview.DefaultView

Private Sub BtnTest_Click(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs) Handles BtnTest.Click
    Dim txt As New DataGridTextColumn()
    Dim s As New Style
    s.Setters.Add(New Setter(TextBox.TextAlignmentProperty, TextAlignment.Right))
    txt.CellStyle = s
    DataGridPreview.Columns(4).CellStyle = s
    'dgvPreview.Columns(4).DefaultCellStyle.Format = "#,##0.00"
End Sub
```

Please point me in the right direction. I'm trying to migrate from Winforms to WPF. And as much as possible I want to do this programmatically. I have also tried using the AutoGeneratingColumn but I can't figure it out.

```
If e.Column.Header.ToString = "Amount" Then        
    Dim dg As DataGridTextColumn = e.Column
    dg.Binding.StringFormat = "#,000.00"
End If
```

Comment: I think "And as much as possible I want to do this programmatically" is a little bit working against WPF.

Comment: @Klamsi I understand. I'll keep an open mind. I am trying to learn after all.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using `AutoGeneratingColumn`, the best time to update the `StringFormat` is on `AutogeneratingColumn` event. Column's binding serves as a blueprint for the individual cells' binding, so for some updates it is important to do them before the cells are created. In C# it will be something like this:

```
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        grid.ItemsSource = Enumerable.Range(0, 10).Select(s => new { Id = s });
    }

    private void DataGrid_AutoGeneratingColumn(object sender, DataGridAutoGeneratingColumnEventArgs e)
    {
            (e.Column as DataGridTextColumn).Binding.StringFormat = "0.000";
    }
```

Comment: Tried it with this `Dim col As DataGridTextColumn = CType(e.Column, DataGridTextColumn)
 col.Binding.StringFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"` . It didn't work.

Comment: Did you call this in the handler method of AutogeneratingColumn? I just tried it on my side with DateTime values instead of int and "yyyy-MM-dd" format and it seems to be working?

Comment: I did. `Private Sub DataGridPreview_AutoGeneratingColumn(sender As Object, e As DataGridAutoGeneratingColumnEventArgs) Handles DataGridPreview.AutoGeneratingColumn`. Did you use c#? Maybe there's something wrong with how I translated it to .net. I'll try looking into it some more.